# mod_rewrite and rewritecond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting to run a rewrite based on a condition in the URI.  In summary, if the uri has a string, and does not contain another string, execute the redirect.  I have an error now, but need some help getting this to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)usb-3-hard-drive(.*) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(*)start$

RewriteRule .* /en/manuals/usb-3-hard-drive/start [L]
```

Request URL: http://www.domain.tld/dir1/**usb-3-hard-drive**/*

New URL: http://www.domain.tld/dir1/usb-3-hard-drive**/start**

Of course, if the conditions do not match, subsequent rewrites should still be honored.

thank you...

Answer (score 3):

What kind of error? You should look into Apache's error log for detailed error message.

In any case -- I suspect that Apache complains on **bad regex syntax**. If it is not a typo on copy-paste (somehow), then the error is here: `!(*)start$` -- there is no such thing as `*` on it's own -- you missed the dot `.` before it -- most likely you meant `!(.*)start$`.

Here is more optimized and fully **working** rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /usb-3-hard-drive/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/start$
RewriteRule .* /en/manuals/usb-3-hard-drive/start [L]
```

BTW -- it does not *"execute redirect"* as you have mentioned -- it only does silent rewrite (internal redirect) when URL will remain unchanged in browser. If you want to have proper redirect (3xx code) when URL changes in browser's address bar, then add `,R=301` (or whatever redirect code you prefer) next to the `[L]`, i.e. `[L,R=301]`.